# this.dataTable.getNumberOfRows is not a function error when mount again react google chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

First time chart components is rendered correctly. When I am changing the tab on dashboard and again click on show charts I am getting error this.dataTable.getNumberOfRows is not a function. When I am mounting chart component again then I am getting error.

chart component:

```
var React = require('React');
var ReactDOM = require('ReactDOM');
var {Chart} = require('react-google-charts');  
var $ = require('jquery');

var LineChart = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            rows: [], 
        }
    },
    componentWillMount: function () {
        this.sTime = this.props.sTime;
        this.eTime = this.props.eTime;
    var _this = this;
    var request = function () {       
        $.post("/times" , {'start':_this.sTime, 'end':_this.eTime }, function (res) {   
            _this.setState({
                rows: res.data
            });
        }); 
    };
    request();
       },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div >
            <Chart chartType="LineChart"
                rows={this.state.rows}
            columns={this.props.columns}
            options={this.props.options}
            />
            </div>
        );
    }
});
module.exports = LineChart;
```

Comment: Is this a valid js code? babel throws exception

Comment: @AndreyBorisko Now it is. Sorry about that. I edit the code. In my IDE whenever we enter it add closing '}' for functions

Comment: where are you defining `_this` ?

Comment: @EricKambestad _this is defined before request function. I edit the code as well.

Comment: @user2194838 any other info from debug? execute `window.localStorage.debug = "*"` in console before running into the issue again.

Comment: @AndreyBorisko Hi did the same. First Time When I am rendering the chart  sequence is constructor,render,ComponentDidMount, render, ComponentDidUpdate, chartLoaded. but second time sequence is constructor,render,ComponentDidMount, draw chart (no data in rows -error), render, ComponentDidUpdate, draw chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to define initial value of rows. This solve the problem.

```
getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        rows: [[new Date(0),0]], 
    }
},
```